# Spring mvc : print element of object inside an object

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

My spring mvc controller:

```
   @RequestMapping(value="/company/{companyname}")
   public String getUserName(Model model,@PathVariable("companyname") String companyname){

       System.out.println(companyname);
       Registration orgInfo=userservice.orgByname(companyname);
       System.out.println("uname:"+orgInfo.getLoginCredentials().getUserName());
       model.addAttribute("orgInfo",orgInfo);

       return "orgProfile";
    }
```

I would like to print the username in jsp file; i tried in this way:

```
${orgInfo.LoginCredentials.UserName}
```

but it says

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'LoginCredentials' not found on type orgProfiles.model.Registration
```

but in my contoller i can print the same like this:

```
System.out.println("uname:"+orgInfo.getLoginCredentials().getUserName());
```

the hibernate query for the orgByname(companyname); is:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        registrati0_.id as id0_,
        registrati0_.address as address0_,
        registrati0_.description as descript3_0_,
        registrati0_.latitude as latitude0_,
        registrati0_.longitude as longitude0_,
        registrati0_.name as name0_,
        registrati0_.place as place0_,
        registrati0_.type as type0_,
        registrati0_.website as website0_ 
    from
        Registration registrati0_ 
    where
        registrati0_.name=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        logincrede0_.logind as logind1_0_,
        logincrede0_.password as password1_0_,
        logincrede0_.userName as userName1_0_ 
    from
        LoginCredentials logincrede0_ 
    where
        logincrede0_.logind=?
unameabc@gmail.com
```

How can i access that object from the jsp file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the JSP you need to access the getters via property notation:

```
${orgInfo.loginCredentials.userName}
```

(Notice the lowercase initals!)

Comment: yes thats it .thanks nfechner!!! i am new to all these stuff like hibernate spring and java . any way thanks thats works great .